# Pyspark low performance for monthly frequency

Tags: apache-spark-sql

There are two tables A , B in Hive A Table has the following columns and is Partitioned based upon Day. We need to extract data from 1st jan 2016 till    31st Dec 2016. I've just mentioned sample but these records are in millions for 1 year. Table A as follows

```
ID Day Name Description
 1   2016-09-01  Sam   Retail
 2   2016-01-28  Chris Retail
 3   2016-02-06  ChrisTY Retail
 4   2016-02-26  Christa Retail
 3   2016-12-06  ChrisTu Retail
 4   2016-12-31  Christi Retail

Table B

ID SkEY
1  1.1
2  1.2
3  1.3
```

The following query is working but taking a long time as the number of columns are around 60(just used sample 3). performance isn't good at all as the result is taking 1 hour for 20 days partitions to process, Can you please figure out and optimise the query.

```
from pyspark.sql import sparksession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark import HiveContext
hiveContext= HiveContext(sc)

def UDF_df(i):
    print(i[0])
ABC2 = spark.sql(
    "select * From A where day ='{0}'".format(i[0])
)
Join = ABC2.join(
    Tab2,
     (
        ABC2.ID == Tab2.ID
    )
).select(
    Tab2.skey,
    ABC2.Day,
    ABC2.Name,
    ABC2.Description
)
Join.select(
    "Tab2.skey",
    "ABC2.Day",
    "ABC2.Name",
    "ABC2.Description"
).write.mode("append").format("parquet").insertinto("Table")

ABC=spark.sql(
    "select distinct day from A where day<= '2016-01-01' and day<='2016-12-31'"
)
Tab2=spark.sql("select * from B where day is not null")
for in in ABC.collect():
    UDF_df(i)
```

Above is the pyspark code for a month that I've considered just to test the total time. A Join B with ID and output ID along with other columns of A.  It's taking 1 hour to complete. Is there any better way of optimising the query by taking either 1 month or 1 year of data. And also output table is partitioned on 2 columns where the data is getting inserted which is why hive contexts are used.

Comment: can you please indent/ format the question so that it should be clear what code snippet is inside the function body and what outside

Comment: Hi Ankit, have formatted the code now, hope it is much more clear. Can you please optimise the code and provide performance efficiency

Comment: i have re-edited the question can you review is that is what you want

Comment: Editing is fine but for a single month it’s taking 1 hour to complete & I need to process for a year. Can you please provide optimisation of the query?

Comment: whats the size of table B and how much memory in spark can you use in ram, can you give me a brief idea about your configrations of spark like how much cores are available and how much ram is there

Comment: Table A for 1 year count is 500 million and table b is 36 million. Not sure about Ram. But the data frame cannot take all 500 million at once so need to be processed in small chunks as like 1 month at a time and loop automatically keeping in view performance

Comment: what i would suggest is don't use loop and instead of collecting write the results in table because collect and toPandas will collect all the data to driver memory and then it will be really slow.

Comment: What part of the result should be written to a table, can you please describe it in a code.

Comment: Hi Ankit, do you know the answer by the way? your questions were more than your actual answers honestly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've build a third table C with three columns -
Start_Date  End_Date Month_No
2016-01-01 2016-01-31 1
2016-02-01 2016-02-28 2
2016-03-01 2016-03-31 3
2016-04-01 2016-04-30 4
2016-05-01 2016-05-31 5
2016-06-01 2016-06-30 6
2016-07-01 2016-07-31 7
2016-08-01 2016-08-31 8
2016-09-01 2016-09-30 9
2016-10-01 2016-10-30 10
2016-11-01 2016-11-31 11
2016-12-01 2016-12-31 12
,
Used a Range[1-12) & then "select * From A where day >=start_date & day<=End_Date & month_no='{0}'".format(i[0]). Called the loop which solved the code.